# Comma operator in FOR loop, how does that work?

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop, comma-operator

Can anyone please explain the comma operator in FOR statement?

```
function funct_1(c){
    for (var a = x, e = y; 0 < c; ){ 
         var p = c/2;
         var c = c/10; // wtf, it is already defined as function argument!!
    }
}
```

Also, the last statement like "a++" seems to be missing. I have never seen anything like this. what does that mean?

Comment: @amnotiam what is it then? I can properly tag it if needed.

Comment: Not sure. The comma will work the same in JS, but JS doesn't have statically typed variables.

Comment: it is js, I know it for a fact ;)

Comment: @user1015551: JS doesn't have `int`.

Comment: ahh damn, my bad, I was rewriting it in C# and copied the wrong code, lol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The comma just adds separation for multiple declarations.  In other words, your `for` loop is setting `a` equal to `x`, as well as `e` equal to `y`.

As for the lack of the increment statement, the fact that it is missing just means that the `for` loop won't explicitly increment any variable.

Comment: Thanks. Also the loop has another definition of 'c' inside it. var c = c/10; how is that possible if c is already declared earlier in the code? does that mean it is treated as a new variable and old c is disregarded within the loop after the new definition?

Comment: @user1015551 not really.  It isn't treating `c` as a new variable, it is just assigning the value of `c/10` back to `c`.  So in other words, if `c` is equal to `200`, and you say `c = c / 10;`, you are basically saying `c = 200 / 10;`.  Make sense?

Comment: yes, thanks man. so why does the code have 'var c = ' inside the loop instead of simply 'c = '. Does using var in this case does have any other meaning or it might as well not be there?

Comment: JavaScript is loosely typed, its not mandated to have `var` but bad practice not to use var. `"use strict";` makes it a requirement to declare your assignment of a scalar to a variable.

Comment: If you don't use `var` in JavaScript you are declaring a global variable which is bad (which is why _strict_ mandates using `var`). And JavaScript has function scoping so any variables declared within the function can be accessed anywhere in the function, i.e. a variable declared inside the loop can also be accessed outside the loop (but only inside the function).

Comment: The thing is there is already a variable 'c' defined before the loop as the function's argument (check edit). so I'm trying to understand what is the reason to use 'var c = ' instead of 'c = ' in this particular situation (not in general)

Comment: @user1015551 good point. Because JavaScript has function scoping, the var part of var c = c/10 is superfluous and the c parameter is already scoped to the function.

Answer (score 2):

The comma just allows you to initialise more than one variable at the start of the loop. And the missing increment operator means that there must be some script inside the loop that will eventually satisfy the termination condition, otherwise the loop would never complete.

Comment: Thanks! does that mean the condition is not defined here? or the condition is c < 0?

Comment: @user1015551 the condition is defined as `0 < c` so as long as _c_ is greater than zero the loop will continue. Presumably somewhere inside the loop _c_ is being decremented and will eventually be equal to zero and the loop will exit.

Answer (score 0):

The comma operator in C, C++, and JavaScript (maybe C#) works like this:

```
comma_operator(statement_1, statement_2) {
     execute statement_1
     return statement_2
}
```

So, in your loop, it initializes two integer values, `a` and `e`, which are set to `x` and `y`, respectively. There is no increment because the loop is comparing against `c`, which is probably set somewhere inside the loop.

Comment: Dunno about C or C++, but the comma operataor works like [this](http://es5.github.com/#x11.14) in javascript. It separates **expressions**, not statements. You can write `var x, y;` which is one statement, you can't write `var x, var y;` which is two statements that must be separated by a semi-colon.